# Cucumber and Spring boot integration

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber-java

I have a microservice application developed using spring boot and used cucumber to test. I have a separate project folder "bdd" where I stored all my features files and the step defns and this project is not deployed in the war file.
I have a requirement where I need to hit the DAO class's methods directly for some testing and I found that from BDD folder, I don't have the access to get the instance of the beans from spring boot.
Found some articles as well on how to integrate the cucumber and the spring boot using the @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) annotations. however It seems not to be working for me.

Does anyone have experience any such requirements or could anyone suggest me on what should be the correct approach.

Thanks.

Edited :
 I am trying to use an instance of  a bean which was initialized already as part of the spring container. when I tried to @Autowire or @Inject using:here registry is the bean instance I am trying to use.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Component
public class AbstractDefs {

    @Autowired
    private static ConnectionProviderRegistry registry;
    dao = new MyDaoClass(registry);
```

the variable registry is still null.

Comment: Try to detail what "it seems not to be working for me" means.

Comment: @metaphori edit the post with more details

Comment: Where is a bean for type `ConnectionProviderRegistry` defined?

Comment: @metaphori ConnectionProviderRegistry bean is defined in another project under the same application. typical folder structure is  MyMicroservice  under which there are BDD (all Cucumber files here)
       and  DATA (ConnectionProviderRegistry is defined here)

Comment: You might have to define a TestConfiguration and specify the Bean you need there